# Best practice in SWIFT to detect whether WKWebview is available?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm developing an iOS app that wrap a single-page-web-app in SWIFT. I'm targeting iOS 7 and above. I'd like the app to use WKWebView and fall back to UIWebView for iOS 7. Detecting the OS version is one way, but I don't think it's the best practice. I know there must be a simple way to detect the feature, but I'm new to SWIFT. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: FWIW, here is [NSHipster's take on the issue](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/), in which he basically suggests the OS version approach (which I don't like, either).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let's wait for the best solution.